# How to parse Apache access log for 404s not from bots?

Tags: apache, apache-log-files, regular-expression

The regex is easy for 404s in a typical Apache log:

```
grep ' 404 ' access_log
```

But many are coming from bots, which I don't care about. I'm looking for actual people hitting 404s. So I'm trying to negate the term 'bot', which comes later in the line, but nothing's working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using the -v (for --invert-match) option of grep:

`grep -v "excluded_word" access_log | grep ' 404 '`

`grep -v "excluded_word" access_log` will return all the lines that don't have the unwanted word and then it is piped to `grep ' 404 '` to list only lines with that pattern.

Since an access_log can be pretty big, a faster way is to use `awk`

`awk '/404/ && !/bot/' access_log` will find `404` and but not `bot`

Answer (score 1):

I find that one of the most useful ways to analyze 404 errors from a log file is to look at the referrer.   You want to know where the 404 error was clicked, and the referrer tells you that.   In addition, bots almost never send the referrer string.  When you look at only records that contain the referrer, it gives you more information and excludes bots.

When no referrer is sent, Apache logs a quoted `-` in that field instead.  So you can use `grep -v` to exclude lines that have only a dash in a field:

```
grep ' 404 ' access_log | grep -v ' "-" '
```

Comment: This is a great idea, but my log syntax contains several instances of " - ". e.g., x.x.x.x - - [16/Jun/2020:16:16:55 -0400]. I'll see about surer ways of finding referrer.

Comment: Here's one that excludes bots and only includes lines with a referrer: grep -v "bot" access_log | grep ' 404 [0-9]* "http.*"' You can define more of the "http" part if you only want to include your domain. That is, to find broken links within your site.

Comment: I forgot the quotes that I now edited it.   The referrer is typically quoted in Apache logs, and it usually the only empty quoted field.      There are more complete ways to parse Apache logs, but this is 99% effective and easy enough to remember.